# Criando aplicativo .exe tipo o phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, css, aplicação-desktop

Gostaria de saber se existe algum aplicativo tipo o `phonegap` que <s>traduz</s> empacota um sistema `html+js+css` em um `.exe`

### Se sim <s>(acredito que exista)</s>

Qual(is) ferramenta(s) existe(m)? Como criar?

Comment: Na verdade o phonegap não traduz, ele empacota o sistema. Talvez isso possa lhe servir (http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14797/can-you-convert-html-css-and-javascript-into-a-exe)

Comment: Vale sem empacotar tudo no exe, mas mesmo assim permitindo criar apps tipo desktop com html/css/js?

Comment: A essas alturas do campeonato.... vale tudo @bfavaretto rs e mais por conhecimento, conheci o phonegap esses dias, e achei bacana a ideia, se houver alguma solução pra desktop, o que vale e funcionar!

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução pode ser usar o [Web2Executable](https://github.com/jyapayne/Web2Executable). Ele gera uma "casca" para os sites utilizando o [NW.js (Node Webkit)](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js).

Para gerar o executável, basta baixar o binário do Web2Executable e rodar a versão de linha de comando:

```
/pasta/do/Web2Executable /pasta/do/seu/projeto
```

ou

```
C:\pasta\do\Web2Executable C:\pasta\do\seu\projeto
```

ou ainda usar a versão GUI (de interface gráfica), que tem a seguinte aparência:

[image: Web2Executable GUI]

Comment: Recomendo que adicione um exemplo do uso disto, como está no Help: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer (leia o trecho Forneça contexto para links) e aproveite pra ler  http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento obrigado pela dica, editei com uma resposta mais verbosa.

Comment: @nighto Tentei utilizar, mas não funcionou....

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio que erro você teve?